# nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: com.zaxxer.hikari:name=dataSource,type=HikariDataSource

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, hikaricp

I have deployed my spring boot application in tomcat-8.5. It works fine as long as one instance of the war is deployed but as soon as I try to deploy next version of same war file (I am trying to do parallel deployment in tomcat), it throws

`Caused by: org.springframework.jmx.export.UnableToRegisterMBeanException: Unable to register MBean [HikariDataSource (HikariPool-7)] with key 'dataSource'; nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: com.zaxxer.hikari:name=dataSource,type=HikariDataSource`.

I know, since one instance is already running with existing hikari pool, deploying another instance is trying to create a different pool with same name and throwing the error because pool already exist.

I can change the pool name every time I deploy a new version of the application but I don't think that would be a good solution.

Is there any better way i can achieve parallel deployment in tomcat without facing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have 2 pools with same name, according to @brettwooldridge [response](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/874)

> each webapp must be configured with a unique poolName property in HikariCP, otherwise their MBean registration names will collide.
>
> It looks like two pools are somehow being created. The second one, with the same name as the first, will fail to register. If you don't declare a poolName then HikariCP will auto-generate them, which will work, but is likely to just cover-up the underlying issue of why two pools are being created. That is either a Spring Boot or JHipster configuration issue ... must likely Spring Boot.

Either don't declare a pool name (if possible) or randomize/add sequence to the pool name

Comment: we are nowhere declaring the pool name. It is probably using default pool name.